# Can AWS Lambda run multiple, specific cron jobs?

Tags: lambda, cron, aws-lambda

I’m a bit confused if this is the right way to use cron jobs/AWS Lambda. Say I have an application that lets users schedule emails and text messages to be sent out and I can do this inside a function sendMessage. Every sendMessage request will have a specific time to be sent out and you only want to send a message/invoke that function one, so I feel like it would be inefficient to set up a cron task on Lambda that checks every second or even minute for new messages to send out. Would it be possible to avoid any repetitive polling like that and just send up a task to Lambda to execute a function at a specific time? Lmk if clarification is needed :)

EDIT: Also this isn’t a code specific question I realize but I tried to ask Software Recommendations and they didn’t have a tag for cron so I figured maybe it wasn’t the right place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah running a Cloudwatch event (CRON) would be pretty inefficient, as it will invoke the Lambda every X minutes even if there is no tasks to be sent. And also you can't create a new Cloudwatch rule for each message to be sent out as the Lambda policy might become too long.

I would suggest you check out [Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html), by using a [Wait State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) to wait until the exact timestamp the message needs to be sent followed by a Task State (to invoke [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connectors-lambda.html) or send to [SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connectors-sns.html) directly).

Comment: Sweet thank u! That’s good to know, I’ll look into step functions and wait states thank u!!!